# python -- check whether module name is valid when assigning to sys.modules

Tags: python

When settings items inside `sys.modules`, some surprising values will are usable as keys:

```
$ python
>>> import sys
>>> sys.modules["27"] = 123
>>> sys.modules["27"]
123
>>> sys.modules[True] = 123
>>> sys.modules[(1, 7)] = 123
```

In fact, `type` identifies `sys.modules` as a standard dictionary... which I found really surprising.

Python2

```
>>> type(sys.modules)
<type 'dict'>
```

Python3 (after type/class unification)

```
>>> type(sys.modules)
<class 'dict'>
```

However, those "modules" are now totally inaccessible using the ordinary `import` mechanism.

Is there a function in the Python standard library that could be used to recognize "good" module names / dot-separate module "path"s. I want to pick out things that are importable using the `import` syntax and generally follow the conventions of the language. Ideally I'd like something that's part of the standard library (if one exists) so that it tracks changes to Python itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*technically* all that's needed for something in `sys.modules` to be "importable" is to be a string as far as I can tell

```
>>> sys.modules['where is your god now?'] = 42
>>> __import__('where is your god now?')
42
```

The restriction is imposed by the `__import__` builtin:

```
>>> __import__(42)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: __import__() argument 1 must be str, not int
```

Even unicode!

```
>>> sys.modules['☃'] = 'looking like christmas?'
>>> __import__('☃')
'looking like christmas?'
```

Though to use the `import` *statement* you need a thing to be an identifier:

```
>>> sys.modules['josé'] = ':wave:'
>>> import josé
>>> josé
':wave:'
```

In python3 you can check if something is an identifier using the `isidentifier` method on strings (for python2, it follows `[a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z0-9_]*` I believe):

```
>>> 'foo'.isidentifier()
True
>>> 'josé'.isidentifier()
True
>>> '☃'.isidentifier()
False
>>> 'hello world'.isidentifier()
False
```

And if you want to handle dotted names:

```
def dotted_name_is_identifier(x):
    return all(s and s.isidentifier() for s in x.split('.'))
```

Usage:

```
>>> dotted_name_is_identifier('foo.bar')
True
>>> dotted_name_is_identifier('hello.josé')
True
>>> dotted_name_is_identifier('hello. world')
False
>>> dotted_name_is_identifier('hello..world')
False
>>> dotted_name_is_identifier('hello.world.')
False
```